# Stacking tests in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Let's just say I have a scenario where I test signing up.

After that, I want to maybe test a bunch of other functionality as a signed in user, sign out,  sign in as a different user, etc etc.

This means that I've set up a whole array of actions; should I be re-running my sign up tests every time? How should I organise my steps/features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Test sign up "is passing" along the way to testing the bunch of other functionality once

After that create a user, and then go through your sign in functionality:

```
Given a user exists with email: "user@gmail.com"
When I go to the homepage
When I follow "Sign in"
When I fill in "Email" with "user@gmail.com"
When I fill in "Password" with "password"
When I press "Sign in"

<<rest of functionality test>>
```

2) You can later condense those sign in steps to just

```
When I sign in as "user@gmail.com"
```

And reuse them for other tests

See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions

2) If the bunch of other functionality is behind authentication, you *have to* test your sign in functionality

3) Come back to your sign up functionality and make a feature and/or scenario for each variation of signing up (email already taken, etc.).  You don't need to keep testing a bunch of functionality afterwards, just check that the sign up worked.  My tests usually say something like

```
The I should see "Dashboard"
```

Which indicates that sign up / sign in was successful